# How to cancel a timed redirection started by a javascript function with a click?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a javascript timed redirection function working properly with the following code, and i would like this function to be cancelled if (and only if) the users click anywhere in the site during the waiting period before the page redirects automatically;

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';",30000);
-->
</script>
```

What code should i use and where ?
Thanks!!

Comment: Use `var timeout = setTimeout("...`. And when you want to stop it, use `clearTimeout(timeout);`

Comment: i only want to stop it   IF   the user clicks in any point of the site.

Comment: are you open to jquery?

Comment: @whispert Oh I understand. I just gave part of the answer

Comment: @whispert:if you are using javascript,have a look at my solution ..it has a working fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In javascript:**

```
var timeout = setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';", 30000);

   window.onclick= function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
     }
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Urexa/1/)

**NOTE**:Fiddle will give error on redirection(as fiddle has some problem loading some other urls) .Its working fine..try it

**Jquery** makes your task super easy though:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';
}, 30000);

$("*").click(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Comment: YES. The in javascript suggestion worked perfect. Thanks a lot folks. Best regards!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should make variable global so you can stop it from wherever you want.

```
var redirect = setTimeout(redirection, 30000);
document.body.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(redirect);
}
function redirecton() {
    location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `window.clearTimeout` to stop it.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var timeoutId = setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';",30000);

    // for some element x
    x.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You need the timer object you got from setTimeOut().

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using jQuery:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';
},30000);

$("body").click(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);    
});
```